# Forfiles /P command issue (not documented?)

Tags: batch-file

I have a scenario:

```
FORFILES /P "C:\users\DominiqueGerry\Work Files\" /S /M *.doc /C "cmd /c echo @fsize"
```

gives me an error:

> ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '@fsize'.
>
> Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.

But when I remove the slash, it works:

```
FORFILES /P "C:\users\DominiqueGerry\Work Files" /S /M *.doc /C "cmd /c echo @fsize"
```

I do not understand why this does not work without the backslash, but does not with it. I cannot find any official documentation explaining this. and do not even see any of it mentioned when running help `forfiles /?` I would appreciate any help on this.

The best part is. The error is not even related to the issue at hand.

Comment: because the trailing backslash is escaping the last double quote. Will post an answer and try explain.

Comment: Some commands require a trailing backslash, some it's optional (`xcopy`), and some don't like it. There is no standard  for commands. Each programmer did their own thing facing problems specific to what they were writing. Windows basic functions attempt to fix wrong paths assuming it can't be confused with a correct path.

Comment: The usage of `forfiles` is a bad idea for this purpose as being extremely slow. For each file a new command process is started just to output the file size. This output is captured by `forfiles` and output in cmd process executing `forfiles`. It is much better for this task to use `for` with the batch file cmd line `for /R "C:\users\DominiqueGerry\Work Files" %%I in (*.doc) do echo %%~zI`. `forfiles` is only more useful in comparison to `for` on using `forfiles` option `/D` whereby often `robocopy` or old `xcopy` are better for file/folder copying/moving tasks based on last modification date.

Comment: @Mofi. Thanks for that, but I actually used a direct example from the `forfiles /?` help. You can see it second last line in the examples when running the help. @catcat, thanks for the comment, but some require \ and some don't, does not really explain the issue at hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be honest, I do not think it is documented anywhere in the official help (at least not what I have seen), but what actually happens is that the trailing backslash is actually escaping the last double quote. In my mind, this is actually a bug.

The reason why the error is not related is simply because the `forfiles` command detects an error in the format, due to the missing double quote, which the backslash escaped.

You will see that this does not happen when you do not have the double quotes, so let's assume you have no space in your path:

```
FORFILES /P C:\users\DominiqueGerry\WorkFiles\ /S /M *.doc /C "cmd /c echo @fsize"
```

Would not give you an error, simply because the baskslash does not have any valid character to escape, problem is, you do have a space in path, so you must use double quotes. So it is best to retain the double quotes and not add the trailing backslash:

```
FORFILES /P "C:\users\DominiqueGerry\Work Files" /S /M *.doc /C "cmd /c echo @fsize"
```

Or if you are adamant on using the backslash, simply escape it by doubling up.

```
FORFILES /P "C:\users\DominiqueGerry\Work Files\\" /S /M *.doc /C "cmd /c echo @fsize"
```

Edit, also as mentioned in comments by **@aschipfl** you can use `.`:

```
FORFILES /P "C:\users\DominiqueGerry\Work Files\." /S /M *.doc /C "cmd /c echo @fsize"
```

Comment: The special interpretation of backslash by `forfiles.exe` is intentionally and not a bug. The reason is the same why also `reg.exe` interprets a backslash left to a `"` or a ``\`` as escape character for the quote/backslash. It makes it possible to define a command argument string (forfiles) or a data string (reg) enclosed in double quotes containing a double quote anywhere in the argument string including beginning and end of the double quoted argument string. But the possible solutions are all fine.

Comment: @Mofi I am not say it was a bug. I said in my mind it is a bug. Meaning that something like this, mostly used on the cmd console, should be documented that being an external command to cmd and how the backslash infuences the outcome.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Your are right, Microsoft's [forfiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles) documentation should explain the special parsing of backslash by `forfiles`. I have requested already once a correction of an error in an example of this official page and I might request also an extension for explaining special parsing of backslashes in all argument strings by `forfiles`. [reg add](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-add) documentation needs also an extension regarding to ``\`` parsing.

Comment: This makes more sense now. I thank you guys for your time.

Comment: I don't think of it as a bug, and here's why... The backslash is the Windows default directory separator, it should only be used when separating the components of the path. There is nothing following the last component, and therefore there shouldn't be a separator.

Comment: @Compo, yes, I understand that, hence me saying in my mind it is a bug, purely because non of this is mentioned in the documentation. The issue for me is, forfiles is not a builtin batch fucntion, but you can only really use it via cmdline interpreter (in standard conditions) even the standard help is only displayed via cmd.exe, so I would expect the documentation to carry this as Mofi also mentioned in his comment, else it is considered a bug.. to me :) So please do not quote me on saying it is an actual bug. I simply expect to read reasons in docs, if something does not work as expected

Comment: If I was writing the documentation, I wouldn't mention it either. Only somebody who doesn't understand that a separator has no place when not separating components would use one. The bug is with the end users understanding, not the developers documentation.

Comment: @Compo well, users, like the OP obviously used other commands where backslash is not a problem, and seeing that it comes from the same windows platform, they would expect usage documentation. It is the same on the likes of `rsync` on linux performs different rasks based on the `\` of both source and destination, but it is documented accordingly. Yes, if forfiles had its own shell, I would not expect documentation as it would probably not be a problem, but you share an interpreter. But anyway, we agree to disagree :)

Comment: The fact that the other command utilities allow the end user to ignore standard convention does not make the Developers of this command utility wrong, the end user still is!

Comment: @Compo not saying they are wrong, I am saying, at least document it.

Comment: I think this should be documented. Use-case I came across is a `forfiles` command to cope with multiple file extensions. `%~dpI` naturally expands to the drive path + a trailing slash, so it needed to be escaped: `for /R "C:\folder" %I in (*.txt *.log) do @forfiles /M *%~xI /P "%~dpI\" /D -90 /C "cmd /c echo @path" 2>nul`. Also, given e.g. the builtin `dir` copes with a trailing slash, I think the natural expectation from users would be that `forfiles` would also.

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ sources compiled into executables may follow [Parsing C++ Command-Line Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/parsing-cpp-command-line-arguments?view=vs-2017)

> Microsoft C/C++ startup code uses the following rules when interpreting arguments given on the operating system command line:
>
> - Arguments are delimited by white space, which is either a space or a tab.
> - The caret character (^) is not recognized as an escape character or delimiter. The character is handled completely by the command-line parser in the operating system before being passed to the argv array in the program.
> - A string surrounded by double quotation marks ("string") is interpreted as a single argument, regardless of white space contained within. A quoted string can be embedded in an argument.
> - A double quotation mark preceded by a backslash (\") is interpreted as a literal double quotation mark character (").
> - Backslashes are interpreted literally, unless they immediately precede a double quotation mark.
> - If an even number of backslashes is followed by a double quotation mark, one backslash is placed in the argv array for every pair of backslashes, and the double quotation mark is interpreted as a string delimiter.
> - If an odd number of backslashes is followed by a double quotation mark, one backslash is placed in the argv array for every pair of backslashes, and the double quotation mark is "escaped" by the remaining backslash, causing a literal double quotation mark (") to be placed in argv.

Quite common for C++ programs. The command interpreter started it's life before
the C++ argument handling mentioned was established. `reg.exe` and other programs
compiled from C++ sources usually have this argument handling.

`forfiles.exe` is not a builtin command to the command interpreter, so the
builtin help of `cmd.exe` will not inform you of how external executables
may behave.

As you have found, you can escape a double quote with a backslash i.e. `\"`.
This allows you to have double quotes in string within double quotes i.e.
`"\"string\""` so that the quotes are retained by the program that the
argument has been passed to. To escape the escape, double up the backslash i.e. `\\`.

The error you receive is 1 double quote of a pair being removed
and the escaped double quote is retained, thus the remaining double
quote causes a syntax error.